# Outlook Addin citrix/termianl installers

Tags: outlook, office-addins, citrix

I have been developing windows application for outlook addin using MS VS2010. I need to develop installer which installs on citrix or terminal server. How do I achieve this? . Is there any third party installers available for free or paid one's ? which would be best option to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is Citrix or a Terminal Server different? It is still a Windows machine, so any installer would work. What is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have registry entries to put as part of installation on citrix.Thanks I will try out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure the registry entries are in HKLM rather than HKCU as the use running your addin will be different from the local user installing it.

Comment: Thanks. And the installation for terminal servers is going to be in [programFilesFolder] or [AppData]? Which would be the more appropriate one?

Comment: Program Files probably makes more sense.